# search values plus characters in a json string

Tags: java

I am trying to search value plus special characters in a json string

my string is `String responseBody = {"name":"rohan","age":32,"loca":"NJ"}` and to be searched is  ActualSearch = `"name":"rohan"`

```
res = responseBody.contains(ActualSearch);
```

I am unable to search this string , IF i give specific values for e.g only "rohan" then it searches fine but "name":"rohan" fails . Please suggest for correct code to search "name":"rohan" as a whole

Comment: Suggestion for correct code: Use a JSON parser. Search the parsed data, where white-spaces and escapes are non-issues.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that you have tried so far.

Comment: I wrote test program for this, you might be able to get the answer by looking at this code:
public class CheckColon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String responseBody = "{\"name\":\"rohan\",\"age\":32,\"loca\":\"NJ\"}";

        System.out.println(responseBody.contains("\"name\":\"rohan\""));


    }

}

Comment: Your snippet code is actually returning true, so I do not see the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"rohan\",\"age\":32,\"loca\":\"NJ\"} ";
        String actualSearch = "\"name\":\"rohan\"";

        System.out.println(json.contains(actualSearch));
```

You should looking JSON Parsers for issues with escape characters

Comment: thanks this worked but is there any other way to just search "name":"rohan" in response string json, this will help in printing the searched values . I am already doing below vjson1 = json.replaceAll("\\\\", ""); to delete the "\" from actual json . Then I get json without "\" and then I need to search "name":"rohan" in vjson1. So can we search without inserting "\" in actualSearch .

Comment: If the above answered your question, please mark it :). as for what you are asking, the representation of a jsonstring is with "\", its used to escape the "".  Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java to get an idea on the Json Parsers, it will come in handy in the future.

Comment: sorry this worked for single one but when I am trying in my actual test it is not working , my string is json = ["{\"isEnriched\":\"true\",\"event\":{\"commonEventHeader\":{\"startEpochMicrosec\":\"1553801673000000\",\"sourceId\":\"\",\"eventId\":\"10.190.201.2-FanFail\",\"internalHeaderFields\":{\"resourceInstanceId\":\"\",\"firstDatetime\":\"Sun, 06 Jan 51208 15:50:00 +0000\",\"serviceInstanceId\":\"N/A\"}}}"]                                                              and I am trying to search "\"eventId\":\"0.190.201.2-FanFail\"" . This failed,please suggest what should be my data to srch

Comment: the eventId in your Json is : "10.190.201.2-FanFail" and your search string is "0.190.201.2-FanFail"